# Find $\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{\cos(1/t)}{t}.$

Tags: calculus, limits

I m stack on finding the limit
$$\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{\cos(1/t)}{t}.$$

Comment: It can be easier if you put $x=\dfrac1t$

Comment: you have $\frac{1}{t} \cos (\frac{1}{t})$. Set $x =\frac{1}{t}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider two sequences $t_n = \frac{-1}{2n\pi} \rightarrow 0^-$ and $s_n = \frac{-1}{(2n+1)\pi} \rightarrow 0^-$.

$$\frac{\cos(1/t_n)}{t_n} = \frac{1}{t_n} \rightarrow -\infty$$
$$\frac{\cos(1/s_n)}{s_n} = \frac{-1}{s_n} \rightarrow \infty$$

By divergence criterion, the limit does not exist.